# VPN using Android DUN and pdaNet

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, android, tethering

I can tether my laptop to my Android phone using pdaNet, but am thus far unable to do a VPN connect on the laptop when connected over DUN via pdaNet.

The pdaNet faq states (http://www.junefabrics.com/android/faq.php):

```
If your VPN server supports standard PPTP or L2TP, you just need to setup VPN on the Android phone (Android 2.0 required) directly: go to Settings->Wireless & networks->VPN settings. After that connect PdaNet and your computer will go through the VPN automatically.

If you have the Cisco VPN which is not supported by Android, just open the property settings of the VPN connection and enable IPSec tunneling over UDP and then it will connect over PdaNet.
```

Which would seem to imply that the Android is the one that has to VPN, but I am not allowed to VPN from a phone, only my laptop.

Does tethering mean the phone is just like a router for the laptop?  If so, shouldn't I be able to VPN from the laptop and not have to VPN from the phone itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around is to use Citrix.  My employer also has a web interface for which the secure id is also accepted to log in.  This can be done over tethered android connection and then Citrix software supplied by employer also most all access I would otherwise get using normal VPN.  Not a great solution, but it is workable.